# Resultado de divisão dá zero nas casas decimais

Tags: c, matemática, ponto-flutuante

Na divisão de 1 por 3, meu programa está imprimindo o seguinte:

> o valor de numero e' de 0.00

Qual é o erro no código?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){  
    float numero;
    numero = 1/3;
    printf("o valor do numero e' de :%4.2f \n\n", numero );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Prefere sempre (\*) usar `double` em vez de `float`. (\*) excepto quando o professor continuar a insistir depois de lhe explicares as vantagens do `double` (e a unica descantagem que nao faz sentido em "programetas").

Answer (score 12):

Porque o código está dividindo um inteiro por outro inteiro.

Usou um número literal que é um valor inteiro. Quando você considera apenas números inteiros, a divisão de 1 por 3 dá 0 mesmo. Depois do cálculo resultar em zero, ele é convertido para `float` pela regra do *casting* automático. Mas note que este *casting* só ocorre com o resultado como um todo e não em cada operando individualmente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("o valor do numero e': %4.2f", 1.0f/3.0f);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ib6hDj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bpuyfvzn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/FloatDivision3.c).

Usando o literal numérico para o tipo de ponto flutuante (1.0f por exemplo), a divisão ocorre da forma correta.

Answer (score 8):

O problema é que a expressão `1/3` é avaliada no contexto de números inteiros. Numa divisão inteira, `1/3 == 0` (a expressão é avaliada antes de ser atribuída à variável `numero`).

Se você usar um valor `float` na sua divisão então você irá ter o valor que espera, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float numero;

    numero = 1.0f/3;

    printf("o valor do numero e':%4.2f \n\n", numero );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float numero,a,b;
    a=1;
    b=3;
    numero = a/b;
    printf("o valor do numero e':%.2f \n\n",numero);
    return 0;
}
```