# Como remover o ultimo número de um inteiro?

Tags: c#, .net, int

Como posso remover o último número de um inteiro?

Ex:

```
int value = 123456789;

int newValue = 12345678;
```

Note que o novo valor não tem o 9.

Sei que seria possível alterar para uma `string` e usar o [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx), mas gostaria de algo sem ser preciso converter para `string`  e depois ter que alterar novamente para `int`.

Comment: Multiplicando por 0.1?

Comment: @Articuno e fazendo cast para inteiro de volta

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pura matemática:

```
123456789 / 10
```

O como o valor é inteiro há um arredondamento decimal automático. Se fosse um tipo que tem casas decimais aí teria que fazer um pouco mais de conta, ainda assim sempre dá para fazer só na matemática.

Veja [funcionando **idenone**](https://ideone.com/zXlNop). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CI049K). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/CutLastDigit.cs).

Comment: Não que eu ligue, só curiosidade mesmo, o que roda mais  rápido, transformar em string e pegar tudo menos a ultima parte, ou fazer a conta?

Comment: Matemática sempre, com grande diferença, mesmo que já fosse *string* e não precisasse converter, e precisa, então fica monstro.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ual... simples e fantástico.

Comment: Sobre divisão inteira: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198271/64969 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43612/64969

Comment: O código de exemplo do link do .NET Fiddle não está compilando.