# Por que o resultado dessa operação está resultando num número inteiro e não "float"?

Tags: c

Por que o resultado do algoritmo abaixo é 1, sendo que deveria ser 1.83?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float y; 
    y = 1 + (1 / 2) + (1/3);
    printf("o resultado é %f" , y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Experimente escrever os numeros com casa decimal (exemplo, `1.0` ao inves de `1`). Do jeito que voce ta fazendo, a linguagem ta interpretando os numeros como inteiros ao inves de ponto flutuante. Ela so vai converter pra float quando for guardar o valor em `y` apos ja ter feito todo o calculo com inteiros, consequentemente resultando em `1`.

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo! Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo você definindo o `y` como `float`, os números da divisão são *inteiros*, logo o compilador `C++` assume que o resultado também será inteiro.

Como o @Leafar falou, para ele realizar a divisão *decimal*, você tem que mostrar que os números são *decimais*.

Uma das maneiras de realizar isso é você adicionar um `.0f` em cada número da operação.

O código ficaria assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float y;
    y = 1.0f + (1.0f/2.0f) + (1.0f/3.0f);
    printf("o resultado é %f", y);
    return 0;
}
```

(Obs: não é necessário colocar o `.0f` em todos, apenas nos `1/` já seria o suficiente).

Links uteis para referencia:

[Resposta do Maniero em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43612/195519)
[Referencia do site *cplusplus* sobre *casting*](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/iG3hAqkS/)

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo! Muito obrigado pela explicação.